# File not selected in form multiple upload in Codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter, upload

so i try to make some upload form which will upload some image. but when the image has chosen then the button submit has clicked the result say "You did not select a file to upload."

im using php, with codeigniter framework

The view

```
<form class="text-left" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?= base_url('aduan/add'); ?>">
<div class="form-group">
                        <label>Upload Foto Bukti Aduan</label>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bukti Aduan 1</label>
                            <input class="form-control-file" type="file" id="bukti1" name="bukti_aduan1" />
                            <?= form_error('bukti_aduan1', '<p class="text-danger font-weight-bold pl-2">', '</p>'); ?>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Bukti Aduan Pelapor di Lokasi</label>
                            <input class="form-control-file" type="file" id="bukti2" name="bukti_aduan2" />
                            <?= form_error('bukti_aduan2', '<p class="text-danger font-weight-bold pl-2">', '</p>'); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

which the view will run the controller "aduan" for input function

Controller file:

```
    $aduan = $this->aduan_model;
        $validation = $this->form_validation;
        $validation->set_rules($aduan->rules());

        if ($validation->run()) {
            $aduan->tambah();

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Berhasil disimpan');

            $data['title'] = 'Buat Aduan Kasus Lingkungan';
            $this->load->view('home/home_header', $data);
            $this->load->view('home/aduansukses');
            $this->load->view('home/home_footer');
        } else {
            $data['aduan'] = $this->aduan_model->getAll();
            $data['title'] = 'Buat Aduan Kasus Lingkungan';
            $this->load->view('home/home_header', $data);
            $this->load->view('home/buataduan');
            $this->load->view('home/home_footer');
        }
```

then the controller will load a model which is "aduan_model"

Model file :

```
public function tambah()
    {
        $post = $this->input->post();

        $this->nik_pelapor = $post["nik_pelapor"];
        $this->nama_pelapor = $post["nama_pelapor"];
        $this->email_pelapor = $post["email_pelapor"];
        $this->telp_pelapor = $post["telp_pelapor"];
        $this->alamat_pelapor = $post["alamat_pelapor"];
        $this->aduan = $post["aduan"];
        $this->bukti_aduan1 = $this->_uploadImage();
        $this->bukti_aduan2 = $this->_uploadImage2();
        $this->status_aduan = 'Dalam proses';
        $this->tgl_aduan = time();
        $this->db->insert($this->_table, $this);
    }
private function _uploadImage()
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';


        // $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        // $config['max_height']           = 768;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ($this->upload->do_upload('bukti_aduan1')) {
            return $this->upload->data();
        }

        return "default.jpg";
    }
    private function _uploadImage2()
    {
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';


        // $config['max_width']            = 1024;
        // $config['max_height']           = 768;


        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('bukti_aduan2')) {
            return $this->upload->data();
        }

        return "default.jpg";
    }
```

i expect the output of image can be stored in file upload and inserted in database but it doesnt select any file

please help :)

Comment: i think you must be call do_upload() function two times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try my code

replace if condition in controller to upload

> > 

```
if(
    (!$this->upload->do_upload('bukti_aduan2')) && 
    (! $this->upload->do_upload('bukti_aduan1'))
)
{
echo "failed";
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}
```